# How do I restore a group of tabs?

Tags: sessions

I just learned about tabs, meaning I can open them via

```
:tabe some/file
:tabe yet/another/file
:tabe foo
```

and circle them via gt (activate right one) and gT (activate left one).

Yet when I close my vim instance via quit-all `:qa`, all my tabs are gone. How can I restore them all when entering vim again?

Answer (score 16):

In vim, there is a feature which allows you to save your current session to a vimscript file.  This can be done using the `:mksession` command.  Here is a synopsis of the command given in the vim documentation:

```
:mks[ession][!] [file]
Write a Vim script that restores the current editing session.
When [!] is included an existing file is overwritten.
When [file] is omitted "Session.vim" is used.
```

You can then load a saved session by running `vim -S Session.vim`.  The `-S` option will take the file given to it and source it before vim starts.  *(see `:h :source`)*  Also, if you omit the file name from the `-S` option, it will try to source a file in the current directory called `Session.vim`.  *(only if `-S` is given as the last argument and the file exists)*

There is an option which allows you to specify what is saved in a session file as well, called `'sessionoptions'`.  This option is a comma separated list of words, with each word enabling the saving or restoring of something via the `:mksession` command.  Here is a list of the possible words in this option and what is saved for each one:

- `blank` - empty windows
- `buffers` - hidden and unloaded buffers, not just those in windows
- `curdir` - the current directory
- `folds` - manually created folds, opened/closed folds and local fold options
- `globals` - global variables that start with an uppercase letter and contain at least one lowercase letter.  Only String and Number types are stored.
- `help` - the help window
- `localoptions` - options and mappings local to a window or buffer (not global values for local options)
- `options` - all options and mappings (also global values for local options)
- `resize` - size of the Vim window: 'lines' and 'columns'
- `sesdir` - the directory in which the session file is located will become the current directory (useful with projects accessed over a network from different systems)
- `slash` - backslashes in file names replaced with forward slashes
- `tabpages` - all tab pages; without this only the current tab page is restored, so that you can make a session for each tab page separately
- `unix` - with Unix end-of-line format (single ), even when on Windows or DOS
- `winpos` - position of the whole Vim window
- `winsize` - window sizes

As an example, the default value for this option would be the following:

```
sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,options,tabpages,winsize
```

For more on these topics, see `:help :mksession` and `:help 'sessionoptions'`.

Comment: nice breakdown! whenever I restore a session I lose the NERDTree window - which is not important but out of interest - do you know if its possible to restore NERDTree using the `sessionoptions` you have described?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way of restoring a Nerdtree window since I don't use that plugin, but it might be because of something special that it does with its buffer s

Comment: Is there a recommended way of automating this?  I don't always have the opportunity to manually create a session before vim is closed.  Manually re-opening a dozen+ tabs each time I return to the machine more than negates the time advantage vim has of being "lightweight" versus a full-fledged IDE startup process that remembers these sorts of things automatically.

Comment: It's not quite fully automatic, but tpope's "obsession" plugin works nicely for me: https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession

Answer (score 11):

You can save a session of vim with all its settings including your open tabs with

```
:mksession ~/session.vim
```

and load it with

```
:source ~/session.vim
```

if you don't want to store options like your colorscheme and font size you can disable storing them with this entry in your vimrc

```
set sessionoptions-=options
```